# Run code on periodic timer after services registered

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I have a class which I'd like to run a method on periodically. I'd prefer to do this with a timer method, so built the class with a method: StartPolling() which would then call my DoSomething() method every 60 seconds.

I tried to start the polling from the Main method in Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);
        ConfigureApp();

        var cam = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<CameraManager>();

        webHost.Run();
    }
```

But when I try resolve an instance (CamerManager) I get an error that other things that CameraManager depends on haven't been registered, e.g. repositories.

What's the best way to do this...and I do not want to use the ABP background jobs as ASP.NET may "go to sleep" so my tasks wouldn't get run on time.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Show code for `CameraManager`.

Comment: Thanks @aaron - the required code is in the Main function where CameraManager is resolved. This line does not execute as camera manager has a dependency injected of CameraRepository, which the IoC Manager says is not registered. So this indicates CameraManager isn't being instantiated, hence no code needed. I think the issue is that the whole pipeline of dependencies is not setup until webHost.Run executes, so my call to resolve CameraManager is a little too early so to speak. Hope that makes sense, and I really appreciate your consideration.

Comment: The situation I am trying to avoid here is building a separate console app to host the polling loop. I am currently prototyping my product, so at this stage trying to keep my project simple and compact. Down the track the polling loop would have to go else where as I separate concerns into different modules.

Comment: `So this indicates CameraManager isn't being instantiated, hence no code needed.` The code is exactly why `CameraManager` isn't being instantiated, so it is needed to reproduce and verify a fix.

Comment: Think of my question this way... ConfigureApp();

        // Can I resolve anything here? Or does the subsequent webHost.Run() have to execute so that the injection would work?

        webHost.Run();